# Ajax Por Form Data= Variável Indefinida

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, html5

Este é meu form

```
<form action='emails.php' method='post' >
<input type='submit' value='Enviar para Email Selecionados'  class='selecionados'/>

</form>


<div class='divtop' style='display:none; '>
<form method='post' action='recebedor.php' enctype="multipart/form-data" id='novo'>
Remetente(Seu Email ou qualquer outro):<br>
<input type='text' name='remetente'  style='width:100px;' />
<br>

Assunto do Email(Título):<br>
<input type='text' name='assunto' class='assuntoo' style='width:100px;' />
<br>
Mensagem:
<br>
<textarea class='mensagemdotext' name='mensaginha' ></textarea>
<br>
Deseja anexar uma imagem após a mensagem?:
<div class='sim'><input type='radio' name='resposta' />SIM </div>
<div class='nao'><input type='radio' name='resposta'> NÃO</div>
<input type='file' class='arquivo' name='arquivu' />
<br><br>
Destinatários(Clientes):
<div class='destinarios'>
<ul>

</ul>

</div>
<input type='submit' value='Enviar Email Agora' />
</div>
</form>
```

Este é meu script

```
$('#novo').on('submit',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = document.getElementById('#novo');
        var dados = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        url:'recebedor.php',
        type:'post',
        data:dados,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(resp) {
                alert(resp);
        }

    });

    });
```

[image]

O problema é logo após a requisição ajax recebo esta mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Imagens de código, não são boas, poderia trocar pela tag código e colocar o código direto em vez das imagens ... se puder fazer isso melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), o método *getElementById* retorna a referência do elemento através do seu *ID*, logo não tem porque utilizar *hashtag*.

```
var form = document.getElementById('novo');
```

Mas você pode utilizar o método [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
var form = document.querySelector('#novo');
```

Comment: Rapazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz num ia achar o erro nunca, programar é dificil né? Um programador web consegue ganhar 1000 por mes? To estudando pra ser um , mt obrigado.